# Is there a word for numbers and letters, but not punctuation, etc?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, numbers

Is there a word that would refer to a number or a letter, but not any other character (like a comma or an exclamation mark)?

Answer (score 12):

An ***alphanumeric*** character is one which is either alphabetic or numeric — that is, either a letter or a digit.  As a noun, we can talk about ***alphanumerics*** for the collection of them, as I do [here in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173294/tags-dont-want-to-play-with-s/173325#173325).

The term *alphanumeric* does not include punctuation, symbols, combining characters (like diacritics), spacing characters, or control characters.

Comment: Ah. Is there a corresponding noun?

Comment: @stephenwade You could just call them alphabetics, the way people call things diacritics (which are usually combining characters).

Comment: Do you mean *alphanumerics*?

Comment: @MετάEd Ulp, yeah.

Comment: Alphanumeric can be used as a noun, but mostly used by itself with the words **character/field/string** implied. Whereas, 'alphanumerics' is a collective term.

Comment: Also, *alphameric*.